# How can I set the IP address value from a URL onto an input field in HTML?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am loading an 'index.html' page where the URL might be http://127.0.0.1:5000/?ip_address=192.168.2.36.

The variable *ip_address* can change when I get to index.html.

I have a form with a submit button that should send the value of ip_address to the controller. My goal is to, be default, set the input field box with the variable ip_address and leave it greyed out, so the user only hits the button.

Is there a way I can get that variable from the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "<h1> Hello World</h1>"

url_for("home" _external=True)
```

The url_for with the option "_external" set to True will create the URL with the IP address.

Comment: `url_for` can only generate the URL for some target that the server is aware of. It cannot get to the information that may be specific to the client. OP is asking about the IP or domain in the URL as it appears in the browser, which the Flask server may not be aware of - only some JavaScript could actually put that in a control.

Comment: i didnt read the qution right... my bad I didn't saw the last part that he wanted to get the value from the URL itself but he can pass the value from the url_for to the frontend...

Answer (score 0):

The following example displays the client's IP address in a text field and sends it to the server. A possibly used proxy or load balancer is taken into account. However, the display of the correct address is not guaranteed. 
If an IP address is already specified in the URL, this will be used to fill in the text field.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    ip_address = request.args.get('ip_address',
        request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-For', request.remote_addr).split(', ')[0])
    return render_template('index.html', **locals())
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="get">
      <input type="text" name="ip_address" value="{{ip_address}}" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```